# Dynamically adjust object names based on parameter

Tags: javascript, apache, function, variables, dynamic

I'm running a script on an apache webserver on a linux box. Based on the parameter I want to change the name of variable(or set it)

The idea is that humDev(lines 11 and 14) is named humDev21 for example. Where devId is the number 21 in this example.

My script looks like this:

```
function getHumDev(devId){
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "/url" + devId,
    success: function(result) {
      var array = result["Device_Num_" + devId].states;
      function objectFindByKey(array, key, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i][key] === value) {
           humDev = array[i].value;
         }
       }
    return humDev;
    };
    objectFindByKey(array, 'service', 'some');
  }
 });
};
```

If Im looking in the wrong direction, please do let me know. Maybe its bad practice what Im trying. The reason I want to have the object a unique name is because this function is called several times by another function, based on the content of an array. But when I have the humDev object named without the number suffix to make it unique, the content of the object is getting mixed up between the different calls.

Comment: make humDev(s) a property(ies) of an object. Then you can dynamically name it whatever you want. `sombObj['humDev' + someVar] = foo;` Since you call the function different times you could make someObj a parameter or use `this` with call/apply.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't figure out how to do this to be honest. In my example, I call the function getHumDev with a parameter devId. Lets assume that the value of that parameter devId is 21. What I want then, is that my line: `humDev = array[i].value;` will be `humDev21 = array[i].value;`   I've tried several things based on your aswer, but I don't see how to get the effect. Can you help me here?

Comment: Why are you using a jQuery ajax call on node.js? that's used to fetch data from the server, you're running on the server?

Comment: Im heavily mistaken there. This is from my script on the web server. Good call. I corrected the initial question. Still don't get how to get this working though.

Comment: In the end, I was able to fit your suggestion in my script. I think it worked right from the first time I added it, but I was distracted by the undefineds I got. But now I'm confident that they are caused by the async calls. When I want to present the data to the html, the api call hasn't finished yet. I'm trying to solve that now in a proper and tidy way with callbacks. Thanks for helping me out on this one!

Comment: Sorry was off yesterday didn't check SO. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I may be off base but I am making some assumptions based on what I understand of what you are trying to do.

First, you need to understand how to do file I/O in `node.js`. So lets start there:

```
var pathToFile, //set with file path string
    fs = require('fs'), //require the file i/o module API
    bunchOfHumDevs = {},
    fileContents; //we'll cache those here for repeated use

fs.readFile(pathToFile, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(); //or however you want to handle errors
    } else {
        fileContents = JSON.parse(result); //assumes data stored as JSON
    }
});

function getHumDev(devId) {

    //first make sure we have fileContents, if not try again in 500ms
    if (!fileContents) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            getHumDev(devId);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        var array = fileContents["Device_Num_" + devId].states,
            i = array.length,

        //if 'service' and 'some' are variable, make them params of
        //getHumDev()
        while (i--) {
            if (array[i]['service'] === 'some') {

                //store uniquely named humDev entry 
                bunchOfHumDevs['humDev' + devId.toString()] = array[i].value;
                break; //exit loop once a match is found
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

getHumDev(21);
```

assuming a match is found for the `devId` 21, `bunchOfHumdevs` will now have a property 'humDev21' that is the object (value?) in question. Also, the `fileContents` are now cached in the program so you don't have to reopen it every time you call the function.

Comment: Its not about filetransfer. And I went wrong in my initial question about the fact I use node.js. I dont use node for this script, but accidentally mentioned that in my post. Nevertheless, your answer did give me some new insights on how to solve my challenge. I'm going to try some stuff within a couple hours. I report back after.